# Перевод кастомного поля в Drupal

Tags: drupal, php

Всем привет!
Делаю мультиязычный сайт на Drupal и перевожу кастомные поля.
есть кусок кода

```
$output .= '<div class="tours">';
$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Day Tour']);
$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Night Tour']);
$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Custom Tour']);
$output .= '</div>';
```

Как перевести это на английский?
тип если язык английский то выводим

```
$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Day Tour']);
```

,иначе выводим русский

```
( $output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Дневной тур']);
```

Помогите чем сможете, очень срочно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант

```
 $day_tour = t('Day Tour');
 $output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und'][$day_tour]);
```

а потом в админке переводить эту строку